# How to upload a csv file to Azure blob storage through Azure functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, powerapps

I am trying to upload a csv file as an output from my azure functions in python. Right now my azure function will run a python script through an http trigger from powerapp and output a json object where I will get that as a response and display it in my powerapp.

Now the project requires me to output an csv file from the azure function and upload it to a azure  storage container. I have no idea what I need to config to bridge to connection from my azure functions to my storage container. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Well documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp

And creating CSV from Python is also well documented ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I was looking for a way where I can just directly upload files to the blob storage without having to config anything. I was able to uplaod files using python from my local machine, would that work if I just use the same code in my azurefunctions without configuring anything?